# Setting up a Crontab for scrapy

Tags: scrapy, cron

I am trying to set up a crontab for scraping something. So far, I wrote

```
23 18 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/Project1 && scrapy crawl xx -o test.csv
```

But when I do that I get this:

```
/bin/sh: scrapy: command not found.
```

What should I do?
I tried to locate the scrapy in my mac but couldn't find it. But I am able run the second part of the crontab task from terminal.

Comment: You don't have the complete path in your CD param

Comment: @BipulJain What do you mean? Should I add the spiders folder? Or should I find where the scrapy is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since crontab doesn't set up PATH variable for you, it doesn't know what `scrapy` is.

The easy way to remedy is to use full path of scrapy:

```
$ which scrapy
/usr/bin/scrapy
```

Then use that instead of just `scrapy`:

```
23 18 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/Project1 && /usr/bin/scrapy crawl xx -o test.csv
```

Another way of doing this is to set the `PATH` environment in your crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
# or your custom path, check your `.bashrc` for PATH you have set in your shell
23 18 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/Project1 && scrapy crawl xx -o test.csv
```

Sidenote:
Also it's very common in cron to wrap your command in some sort of script that populates the `PATH` and other configurations and calling that script in cron instead of calling the commands directly.

Comment: Side note: I am using Mac, hence my path of scrapy comes out different when I wrote 'which scrapy'

Comment: @AliyarÖzercan Could you post the entire crontab file? The error mentions "Applications" command not found but it's not mentioned anywhere in your text. Also you should probably use absolute path in your cd command. e.g. starting with `/home/user/myproject`

Comment: @AliyarÖzercan it's a bit hard to read in this format, could you post in original formatting on some pastebin? i.e. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @AliyarÖzercan the log you posted still uses `scrapy` instead of absolute path of it (i.e. `/usr/bin/scrapy`).

Comment: @AliyarÖzercan PATH should contains a list of directories separated by `:`. So instead you should have `PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` (without `scrapy`)